# How to install web3j command line to generate smart contract wrapper

Tags: go-ethereum, web3j

I am trying to generate a simple smart contract wrapper using solc and web3j in ubuntu.

I have downloaded the source as defined in https://docs.web3j.io/command_line.html

Release package can be obtained from https://github.com/web3j/web3j/releases/tag/v4.1.0.

I have download the source from https://github.com/web3j/web3j/archive/v4.1.0.zip

After unwrapping the zip package I can't find any bin directory as the document page shows

```
unzip web3j-<version>.zip
creating: web3j-3.0.0/lib/
inflating: web3j-3.0.0/lib/core-1.0.2-all.jarcreating: web3j-3.0.0/bin/
inflating: web3j-3.0.0/bin/web3j
inflating: web3j-3.0.0/bin/web3j.bat
```

How to get the bin directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4.1.0 binary package is not attached yet in https://github.com/web3j/web3j/releases

I have to download package for 4.0.1 from https://github.com/web3j/web3j/releases/download/v4.0.1/web3j-4.0.1.tar

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to install web3j, I consider you to use the version 3.5.0 because it's stable and reliable. 
Then you can generate your contract wrapper. It's very simple

```
$ web3j truffle generate [--javaTypes|--solidityTypes] /path/to/<truffle-smart-contract-output>.json -o /path/to/src/main/java -p com.your.organisation.name
```

Now you can just import your new generated package and use it's class. 
Remember to use web3j 3.5.0 in your gradle/maven project as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -L get.web3j.io | sh && source ~/.web3j/source.sh
```

Ubuntu 20.04, web3j release from July 2022

```
web3j --version 

by Web3Labs
Version: 1.4.1
Build timestamp: 2021-02-16 20:28:33.742 UTC
```